# take an array of attributes to make a hash of only those attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Item class with many attributes but for this case lets say it has a name, detail, inventory_count, price on it. in These are all ruby primitives.

I would like to get back a hash of like 'name' and 'detail' such that:

```
vals=%[name detail]

item=Item.find(23)

# somethign like???

g={}
vals.map { |atr| g[atr]=item.??? }
```

or some other technique. How would I take a string representation and get the attribute of an instance? Is there an easier / better way to do this?

#### edit 1

looks like `send` might do it. Let me check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`#attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes) returns an object in hash representation, [`#slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) returns a hash containing only the given keys, so:

```
item.attributes.slice('name', 'detail')
```

Comment: cool - how would I pass an array of desired attributes into slice()?

Comment: @timpone just unpack array like this: `item.attributes.slice(*array)`